# How do I complete hundreds of concatenations in MSExcel (2013)

Tags: concatenation, excel-2013

I have a spreadsheet with 202 rows and 692 columns. How do I concatenate the 692 columns for each of the rows?

I have tried this on a smaller dataset: =CONCATENATE(B2:G2&","), then use F9 to replace the B2:G2 with the contents of those cells. That works fine, but I can't copy it down to the other rows. Also, when trying in my real data (692 columns), there are too many data fields for excel to complete the concatenation.

Any tips please? I'm unfamiliar with coding and have only a basic level of excel knowledge.

Comment: copy the formula down before you replace the row. likely just concat in a new column and then copy the output back to the first when you're done.

Comment: That's a lot of concatenation, which makes me think: is a spreadsheet even the best tech here? Would a search/replace in a text editor be better? But we don't know if the data is live, or format, or what. Adding some context might help.

Comment: Thanks Joshua and Anders8. All sorted now. Anders8 - I agree a spreadsheet is not the best for this data! Unfortunately, that is what I have been provided with and the concatenation was a step towards getting the data into a database. Again - thanks for your comments.